# обработка кириллицы в BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, utf-8, кириллица

пытаюсь получить сайт, и распарсить его с помощью `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.urlopen("http://site-cyrillic.ru").read()
soap = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser");

print(soap);
```

возвращает просто пустую строку. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
 
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

*на сайте без использования кириллицы, все успешно проходит**

Comment: Вы уверены что `r` что-то содержит?

Answer (score 1):

это скорее касалось случая, если кириллица присутствовала в URL (в кодированном виде с "%"). Мне кажется в вашем случае дело может быть в `urllib.request` - нужно проверить, возвращается ли значение. Также посмотреть на наличие ошибок:

```
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

req = urllib.request.Request("http://site-cyrillic.ru")

try:
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
    print('Error code - ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
    print('Reason - ', e.reason)
else:
    print('Successful')
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, какая версия Puthon используется? Во-вторых, можно попробовать проверить кодировку сайта:

```
r = urllib.request.urlopen("http://site-cyrillic.ru")
r.headers['content-type']
```

Может оказаться, что сайт в windows-1251.

Comment: 3.5 v. получается `BeautifulSoup` не поддерживает кодировки кроме `UTF-8`? допустим, станица возвращается не в `UTF-8`.. как решить проблему?